# IBM Worklight 6.2 Server Deployement error: DB2 Instance not found on server

Tags: db2, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-server, websphere-liberty, database-cluster

**Environment:**

1. IBM Worklight 6.2,
2. IBM Liberty 8.5.5.1,
3. IBM DB2 10.5 &
4. Windows 2008 standard Edition.

For the High Availability of DB instance[WLDBINST], the following Architecture I have followed.

1. 2 Windows Clustered Machines with IBM DB2 binary and SAN storage used to share the Database file in Common.
2. If any 1 node is not available the other node will take over the control without any loss of the data.
3. I have tested the DB2 instance via Cluster IP and it works fine.

The below error has been logged, when I run the Worklight Server Configuration tool,

```
Instance WLDBINST not found on server. Found only [WLDBINST              C, :, DB2CLUSTER, DB2]
```

I have found the reason for the above issue. To list the DB2 Instances we can use the command db2ilist

```
C:\>db2ilist
WLDBINST        C :    DB2CLUSTER
DB2
```

Above result shows that we have two instances

1. WLDBINST which is in "C" drive and part of DB2CLUSTER &
2. DB2

Worklight Configuration tool also uses the similar DB2 tool to list the instances, I guess.

So the configuration tool considering the result as 4 instances as follows,

1. WLDBINST       C,
2. :,
3. DB2CLUSTER and
4. DB2

How I can resolve this issue.

Comment: Can you check to see if there are any SSH-related errors in the Windows event logs on the DB2 server system?  There is an issue with the IBM SSH Server that's provided with DB2 10.5 Fix Pack 3 (and previous, I would assume) that can cause strange problems with the Server Configuration Tool talking to a DB2 server on Windows Server 2008.  If this is the problem, you might see errors in the event log that look like "error: [do_spawn in session.c @545] error assign process to job object 5".  The problem is fixed in DB2 10.5 Fix Pack 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the Server Configuration Tool is not able to create the database for your topology, you should create it manually before running the tool.

For the Administration database, the doc is here:
https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.2.0/com.ibm.worklight.installconfig.doc/admin/t_creating_the_db2_database_for_wladmin.html

For the Project Runtime databases, the doc is here:
https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.2.0/com.ibm.worklight.deploy.doc/admin/t_creating_the_db2_databases.html

The server configuration tool will not do any specific configuration to ensure that Liberty reopens a connection if there is a database node switch. I recommend that you review the behavior of Liberty in this case, and add settings in the server.xml as required.

Comment: Problem is Worklight Server configuration tool unable to fetch the DB2 instance name properly which I clearly mentioned in the question. But your answer is creating the Database manually. Even if I create a database manually, will Server Configuration tool can fetch the DB2 instance? I agree, Server configuration tool doesn't have relation with switch node that's why Cluster IP has been used. I wanted to explain what is the environment with the nodes. What you want me to review in server.xml? What setting's do I need to add?

Comment: If the database is created manually, the server configuration tool should be able to populate it with the right tables without a need to know the instance. It should also be able to proceed with the war deployments.

Comment: How a .war can be deployed without knowing the DB instance? In my scenario I have two instances with the tables, as per your comment how server config tool will decide the instances. If server configuration tool can populate the tables without a need to know the instance then why we need an option to choose?

Comment: Different DB2 instances on the same machine use different ports for the JDBC connection. In the "Database Settings" panel of the Server Config Tool, you can enter the port number. This port number identifies the DB2 instance. The instance name is not needed once the database and schema already exists.

Comment: The DB instances should be distringuished by the listening port that you need to enter in the Server Configuration Tool. Have you tried the workaround proposed ? Does it create an issue ?