# IBM MobileFirst IBM DB2 "no DB2 instance found on the server"

Tags: db2, ibm-mobilefirst

Environment:

- IBM MobileFirst 7.1
- IBM Liberty Core 8.5.5
- IBM DB2 10.5
  0 Windows Server 2012 R2

While installed the `IBM Mobile First 7.1` platform, in Database Creation request step, I am getting message `No DB2 instance found on the server`.

However on `db2ilist` it returns default instance as "DB2".

Any idea why it's not listing while Mobile First installation in database creation step?

Comment: Please take a look at this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26246307/ibm-worklight-6-2-server-deployement-error-db2-instance-not-found-on-server

Answer (score 0):

This question may be a duplicate of: [IBM Worklight 6.2 Server Deployement error: DB2 Instance not found on server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26246307/ibm-worklight-6-2-server-deployement-error-db2-instance-not-found-on-server)

As the answer mentions, it seems the Server Configuration Tool may not able to create the database for your specific topology. You should then create it manually before running the tool. For instructions, see: https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.2.0/com.ibm.worklight.installconfig.doc/admin/t_creating_the_db2_database_for_wladmin.html

For the Project Runtime databases, the doc is here: [IBM Worklight 6.2 Server Deployement error: DB2 Instance not found on server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26246307/ibm-worklight-6-2-server-deployement-error-db2-instance-not-found-on-server)